# input by the user is not obtained by onblur function

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying form validation in javascript and html. I am stuck with the use of onblur(). The idea is that the user enters his name. If he moves out of the input area (textbox) without entering anything, then error message should be shown. 
But according to my code below even if I enter anything, it still shows alert no name entered.

```
   <form>
            <input type="text" id="fn" value="First Name" onfocus="fnm()"        onblur="chfnm()"/>
    </form>

    function fnm()
    {
            document.getElementById("fn").value="";  //clears default value of textbox
    }

function chfnm()
    {  
            var f=document.getElementById("fn");    
        for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++)
            {
                    if(i!=(f.length-1))
                            fname= fname +f.elements[i].value +"<br>";
                    else
                        fname= fname+ f.elements[i].value;
            }

            if(fname=="")  //error is fname is always an empty string
            {
                    alert("Please fill your first name");
                    document.getElementById("fn").focus();  
            }


    }
```

I am new to javascript so any new ideas are appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do validate that user inputting the name or not, you can simply use this code. If so you are putting extra code with `for loop`.

```
function fnm(){
        document.getElementById("fn").value="";  //clears default value of textbox
}
var fname = "";
function chfnm(){ 
    fname = document.getElementById("fn").value;    
    if(fname==""){  
        alert("Please fill your first name");
        document.getElementById("fn").focus();  
    }else{
        alert("your name " + fname);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ94p/)

Comment: If answer is what you wanted, please mark it as accepted answer that other can get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add required tag of html5 so no need to add extra java script function for checking

Comment: But can you tell me what is wrong with the above code?